# Assistance in data filtering using Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse, data-filtering

I have a table that summarizes ~100 clinical trials. This table needs to be added to a shiny app and then the user filter the table based on the different variables in the table like endpoint, intervention, etc.

The problem with that the table is that every study, as far as I know, has to be in only one row. But in excel, each study needs more than one row since variables like "Intervention" and "Endpoint" has so many levels, and I will need to subset on my data based on these variables.

For example, user choose to subset on studies that included outcome 1 or maybe intervention 1. Many studies has a mix of these, as in the screenshot below.

This makes it impossible for each study to fit in one row especially that a study can have up to 15 different interventions (there is a long list of interventions that the use will subset based on)

How to approach this?

[image: sample]

Comment: (1) It looks like you are having difficulty dealing with that data, _period_, which means that asking first about [tag:shiny]-integration is too soon. Solve the basic data problem first, _then_ try to make it fancy/interactive. (2) Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to figure out how to "fill in" all of the empty rows with the preceding row's data. Ignoring the [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) component for now, if I have data (in xlsx, though it doesn't matter if CSV) like the following:

[image: spreadsheet with sparse rows]

We can read in and fix with `zoo::na.locf` or `tidyr::fill`:

```r
dat <- readxl::read_excel("~/Downloads/something.xlsx")
dat
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   Author    Year Methodology    `Intervention(s)` `Endpoint(s)`
#   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>          <chr>             <chr>        
# 1 X et al.  2022 Prospective    Intervention 1    Endpoint 1   
# 2 NA          NA NA             Intervention 2    Endpoint 2   
# 3 NA          NA NA             Intervention 3    Endpoint 3   
# 4 Y et al.  2021 Something else Intervention 4    Endpoint 4   
# 5 NA          NA NA             Intervention 5    Endpoint 5   
# 6 NA          NA NA             Intervention 6    Endpoint 6
```

and fix with *one* of the following:

```r
tidyr::fill(dat, Author, Year, Methodology)
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   Author    Year Methodology    `Intervention(s)` `Endpoint(s)`
#   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>          <chr>             <chr>        
# 1 X et al.  2022 Prospective    Intervention 1    Endpoint 1   
# 2 X et al.  2022 Prospective    Intervention 2    Endpoint 2   
# 3 X et al.  2022 Prospective    Intervention 3    Endpoint 3   
# 4 Y et al.  2021 Something else Intervention 4    Endpoint 4   
# 5 Y et al.  2021 Something else Intervention 5    Endpoint 5   
# 6 Y et al.  2021 Something else Intervention 6    Endpoint 6   

dat[] <- lapply(dat, zoo::na.locf)
dat
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   Author    Year Methodology    `Intervention(s)` `Endpoint(s)`
#   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>          <chr>             <chr>        
# 1 X et al.  2022 Prospective    Intervention 1    Endpoint 1   
# 2 X et al.  2022 Prospective    Intervention 2    Endpoint 2   
# 3 X et al.  2022 Prospective    Intervention 3    Endpoint 3   
# 4 Y et al.  2021 Something else Intervention 4    Endpoint 4   
# 5 Y et al.  2021 Something else Intervention 5    Endpoint 5   
# 6 Y et al.  2021 Something else Intervention 6    Endpoint 6
```

From here, you can filter however you need without losing information on the author/year/etc.

Comment: This is great solution. But when we present the final table in a shiny app, each study will be repeated multiple times. For example X et al., according to your table will be present three times. How to avoid this?

Comment: I think you need to consider the difference between data "to work on" and data "rendered for aesthetics". I think the latter is what you're talking about is rendering, which can be handled well with packages like `gt` or `DT`, perhaps. However, a quick hack might be something like `dat[,1:3] <- lapply(dat[,1:3], function(z) ifelse(c(FALSE, z[-length(z)] == z[-1]), "", z))` (where `1:3` are the columns you want to "deduplicate").

Comment: Can you give me an example of how this can be implemented in Shiny? I tried this code but didn't show the results. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `shiny`. If you can do this on a console, you can do it in `shiny`. If you don't know how to put this into a reactive component of a `shiny` app, then I suggest you step through shiny tutorials to learn about reactivity, such as https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html.